# without type='text/javascript' is okay for ie9?

Tags: javascript

I already know the current browser's default script is javascript.

That's why there's no problem if we don't type the attribute "type".

But how about old browsers? eg. ie8 or ie9

Is it also okay for them?

Comment: Try it out.....! Why do you want to exclude it ?

Comment: @RayonDabre cuz simple. it makes code short.

Comment: @RayonDabre got it!! thanx. so it depends on the version of html doctype, not the version of browser.